# PHP - Why it shows code content after the greater than >

Tags: php

I try to run a PHP page. But it always shows source code content after greater than symbol ( > ) until meet the ( ?> )

For example:
My Code is:

```
<?
    require_once('includes/global.php');
    include_once('includes/auth.php');

    .... // bla bla bla

    $stats = STATS::singleton();
    $stats->parse_all();

    $product = PRODUCT::singleton();
    $product->getNewVersion();
    $product->getInstalled();
?>
... // bla bla bla
```

And when I run the page, it will display on browser as below:

```
parse_all(); $product = PRODUCT::singleton(); $product->getNewVersion(); $product->getInstalled(); ?>
```

Before parse_all() is the greater than symbol. And it stops displaying code content until ?>

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your file is not being evaluated as PHP. How are you "running" that page?

Comment: you might have short tags disabled in php.ini

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put `<?php` in the beginning not `<?` if you don't have short tags enabled

If you want short tags enabled you need to put this `short_open_tag=On` in your `php.ini`

If you don't have access to your `php.ini` you can also do this in an `.htaccess` with this `php_flag short_open_tag on`

See the link [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) for the explanation of short tags.

Comment: I set short_open_tag=On in php.ini
I also tried to put @ini_set( 'short_open_tag', true ); in the beginning of the code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried to put @ini_set( 'short_open_tag', true ); in the beginning of the code, but it doesn't work

Comment: @JackBui is this on your local machine or on a hosted server?

Comment: on my host server, running lite speed webserver. and exactly, i'm trying to run the admin page and it's got problems

Comment: @JackBui hmm...does the file have the extension `.php`

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, I don't know why, but there're a lot of PHP on my host server. When I echo phpinfo in my webpage, it shows short_tags On, but when I tried to echo phpinfo in the admin page (that's got error) it shows short_tags Off. I'll take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: @JackBui I would suggest just putting `<?php` instead of using short tags.  From what I read you shouldn't be using short tags because it can cause issue with `xml` and `asp` tags

Comment: I am using PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS ) on Ubuntu. I do not have any short tags - all <?php tags but still seeing this problem. When I search 'grep -ir "<?" *.php', I see a lot of results. But when I search for 'grep -ir "<?" *.php | grep -v php' to check for any short tags without php, I don't see any results; implying that my code is OK. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have php installed and setup, you may not have short tags enabled wihin you `php.ini`:

So change **all** `<?` to `<?php`